# Update if there is no such element

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document

```
{
 videoSection:{
   title: "Social construction",
   videos: [
    {title: "a", isApproved: true},
    {title: "b", isApproved: false},
    {title: "c", isApproved: true},
   ],
   isPublished: false
 }

}
```

I need to update the document (to set `isPublished: true`) if all the `isApproved` fields of the videos of videoSection is `true` which means if there is no  `isApproved = false`.

What is the way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- check condition if `isApproved` is not false then update `isPublished` to true

```
db.collection.updateMany({
  "videoSection.videos.isApproved": {
    $ne: false
  }
},
{
  $set: {
    "videoSection.isPublished": true
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ju46QROaf7e)

Answer (score 2):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/obReFQ3FmkV

```
db.collection.update(
{
   "videoSection.videos.isApproved": {
     $exists: true,
     $ne: false
   }
},
{ $set: { "videoSection.isPublished": true } },
{ multi: true }
)
```

Note -  `{ $exists: true }` this add extra checks for the case where videos array is empty or not present, update will not happen.

Comment: 1 Thanks for kind contribution!